# PHP difference between dates always displaying 0

Tags: php, date

Im trying to take 2 dates and subtract them from each other

```
$now = date('2014-07-17');
$due = date('2014-07-20');

$diff = $now - $due;
$timeRemaining = floor($diff/(60*60*24);
```

This just returns 0 everytime when it should be 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`date()` takes a string format and Unix Timestamp as a parameter, not just a literal date string. So both calls to `date()` is returning the original value to you since both are invalid arguments. [Type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) due to the subtraction of strings returns `2014` for both of those variables and the result then is they are equal.

Use `strtotime()` instead which returns the timestamp you are expecting and can do your date math with.

Also, you need to put the later date first if you want a positive integer as a result.

```
$now = strtotime('2014-07-17');
$due = strtotime('2014-07-20');

$diff = $due - $now;
$timeRemaining = floor($diff/(60*60*24);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're subtracting two strings, which get [type juggled](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to the integer value `2014` for each string, which will of course return `0`.

```
$now = (int) date('2014-07-17'); // Will make $now = 2014
```

Here's a way to do it (but I'd recommend using `DateTime` objects instead):

```
$now = strtotime('2014-07-17');
$due = strtotime('2014-07-20');

$diff = $due - $now; // Notice how you had your original equation backwards
$timeRemaining = floor($diff/(60*60*24));
```

Here's how to do it with [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) objects:

```
$now = new DateTime('2014-07-17');
$due = new DateTime('2014-07-20');

$diff = $due->sub($now);

$timeRemaining = $diff->format('%d');
```

Comment: Actually, type juggling means they aren't subtracting two strings.

Comment: @JohnConde Edited for clarification

Comment: Cool. +1 for using DateTime and DateInterval. I'm a big fan of using them for date math for many reasons.

Comment: @JohnConde Agreed, it saves time from having to write math and conversions like OP is trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `strtotime`, not `date`. And you need to reverse your subtraction formula - the earlier date(`$now`) should be subtracted from the future date(`$due`).

```
$now = strtotime('2014-07-17');
$due = strtotime('2014-07-20');

$diff = $due - $now;
$timeRemaining = floor($diff/(60*60*24));
```

[**See Demo**](http://codepad.org/mRcplbik)